# Why is zookeeper complaining about address in bind when port is free?

Tags: windows, port, apache-zookeeper, netstat

When trying to run Zookeeper locally on Windows, I currently receive the error message

`java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind`

suggesting that my port 2181 is not available. However, a quick netstat analysis

`netstat -ano | findstr :2181`
in cmd does not yield any process on that port, see screenshot attached. Any help on what may cause this issue greatly appreciated!

[image: Zookeeper Error and Netstat result]